# Is it necessary to Flush the Steam during a internet read file (download) process?

Tags: c#, stream, download, buffer, flush

I'm working on a download method with resume support in my application (inside a thread).

My application users usually has *low internet speed* (common `between 10 to 50 kbps` download speed) and target files are `between 3 to 80 MB`...

A part of my download codes:

```
// Buffer size = 1024000 bit = >>
int iBufferSize = 1024;
iBufferSize *= 1000;

    /// some codes.....

Try{

    /// some codes.....

    request = HttpWebRequest.Create(sourceUrl);

    request.AddRange((int)downloadedSize)

    Stream smRespStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    const int MAX_LOOP=5;
    var flushStreamCounter = 0;
    while ((iByteSize = smRespStream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
         saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, iByteSize);


         //----------------------------------
         //            some codes
         //----------------------------------


         // Are these codes necessary to really write data to file now (when the condition is true)?
         flushStreamCounter++;
         if (flushStreamCounter > MAX_LOOP)
         {
             saveFileStream.Flush();
             flushStreamCounter = 0;
         }
    }
}
finally
{
      if (saveFileStream != null)
       {
          saveFileStream.Flush();
          saveFileStream.Close();
          saveFileStream.Dispose();
        }
}
```

When i know the intenet speed is low for my customers i won't lost downloaded data by internet disconnect interrupts or application force closing or PC power off...

So, My Questions:

- Should i use `Flush` method of `saveFileStream` to write data from memory to hard disk during `while` loop to prevent lost data, when i know the users maybe force close my application during download or intenet DC or...?
- If using `Flush` is good way and necessary then what is the best `MAX_LOOP` value in my case and why?
- What is the best `iBufferSize` value for my application (base on application user's internet speed) and why?

---

**Update:**

I don't know what are the *advantages* and *disadvantages* of using `Flush` stream **during `while` loop**!

When download process of my application is running, the windows explorer dose not show the file size increasing (even by Refresh). It updates the file size after above method complete, so i don't know is it a danger to lost data on application force closing or PC power outage.

Comment: If you send big file with low speed, then you should provide an interruption recovery. Split data into small portions (at first send small info data: file size, number of portions, etc.), each portion should have header with at least CRC (data can be zipped as well), splitting process should yield the same result for same file (to be able to resume download). If portion successfully received -> flush it and request next one, when all portions are received -> create final file and say "download is completed", if portion CRC doesn't match (or timeout, etc.) -> re-request same portion.

Comment: @Sinatr, my written application has resume support by using `request.AddRange((int)downloadedSize)`, so if the user close it, the file will be complete next time by resume downloaded feature but my question is about really write data to file during `while` after some loop. I don't know what are the _advantages_ and _disadvantages_ of using `Flush` stream during `while` loop! When download process of my application is running, the windows explorer dose not show the file size increasing (even by Refresh). I don't know is it a danger to lost data on application force closing or PC power outage.

Comment: It is (data will be lost) and flush won't help. The point is to save small chunks (portions). If power breakage occurs, your software is restarted and it will check chunks again (including CRC) to check *data consistency*. Then it will continue downloading missing chunks. I don't see any such mechanics in your code, that's why I try to explain it more-less fully.

Comment: OK, if flush won't help anymore, so i think my download method is good enough in this case (with resume support) and i can remove Flush part from while loop.